Configurable widget doesn't show a list of dynamic values
I'm developing an iOS app with Swift 5.9, SwiftUI, Xcode 15.3 and Firebase. My deployment target is iOS 17. I've faced a problem when creating a new configurable widget using WidgetConfigurationIntent.
The widget is using Firebase Authentication and Firestore to download user's documents ("Deck") and display them as a list of values in widget's configuration.
When I'm running my widget in a simulator (also using my device as a run destination), the widget works fine. But when I run it on device (without running from Xcode), the list of values doesn't open. I know that dynamic list was successfully fetched because the first item from the fetched array was chosen as a default parameter.
I'm new at programming so I'd be grateful if someone can help me.
struct SelectDeckAppIntent: WidgetConfigurationIntent {
    static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "Select deck"
    static var description = IntentDescription("Select a deck to display information for.")
    
    @Parameter(title: "Deck")
    var deck: DeckEntity
    
}

struct DeckEntity: AppEntity {
    
    let id: String
    let title: String
    
    static var typeDisplayRepresentation: TypeDisplayRepresentation = "Deck"
    static var defaultQuery = DeckQuery()
    
    var displayRepresentation: DisplayRepresentation {
        DisplayRepresentation(title: "\(title)")
    }
    
    static func getAllDecks() async throws -> [DeckEntity] {
        guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AppError", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Authentication failed or user not logged in"])
        }
        
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let ref = db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("decks")
        let snapshot = try await ref.getDocuments()
        
        return snapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> DeckEntity? in
            guard let title = document.data()["title"] as? String else {
                return nil
            }
            return DeckEntity(id: document.documentID, title: title)
        }
    }
    
}


struct DeckQuery: EntityQuery {
    
    func entities(for identifiers: [DeckEntity.ID]) async throws -> [DeckEntity] {
        try await DeckEntity.getAllDecks().filter { identifiers.contains($0.id) }
    }
    
    func suggestedEntities() async throws -> [DeckEntity] {
        try await DeckEntity.getAllDecks()
    }
    
    func defaultResult() async -> DeckEntity? {
        try? await suggestedEntities().first
    }
}


I've tried reinstalling the app but it didn't help.  Also, I've tried using hard-coded array using static let allDecks: [DeckEntity] = [...] and in this case the list works fine. I don't know what is wrong but I guess the problem is somewhere in WidgetConfigurationIntent, AppEntity or EntityQuery.
